# How do I reset my me.com email password

Tags: password

I have a me.com email account and I need to reset my password but cannot figure out how to do it.  I need assistance in finding out how to reset it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you visit me.com you are redirected to icloud.com.  Given this info it should be the same the password as your appleid, if you have forgotten that then go to http://iforgot.apple.com to reset the password.